# How to manually add messages to tf::MessageFilter?

Tags: ros, filter, message-filter, message-filters

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Is it possible to manually add messages to a tf::MessageFilter queue instead of connecting the filter's input to a subscriber? The add(...) methods provided in the API only seem to work with other filters as argument.

Thanks,
-Robert-

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/29705/how-to-manually-add-messages-to-tf::messagefilter?/) by [Robert Krug](https://answers.ros.org/users/1269/robert-krug/) on ROS Answers with karma: 225 on 2012-03-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Enrique](https://answers.ros.org/users/244/enrique/) on 2012-03-14**:
I don't see the use case. BTW, why don't you create a publisher and subscribe to it, so instead of add(...) you only have to publish. It'd have the same effect, wouldn't it?

**Comment by [Robert Krug](https://answers.ros.org/users/1269/robert-krug/) on 2012-03-14**:
It would, but publisher & subscriber would be in the same node and I don't really need those specific messages anywhere else so I wanted to avoid creating unnecessary topics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The add method works for messages [API docs](http://ros.org/doc/electric/api/tf/html/c++/classtf_1_1MessageFilter.html#ac1336ff0ed4fd8122d27011b14053a0d)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-03-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Robert Krug](https://answers.ros.org/users/1269/robert-krug/) on 2012-03-14**:
Ah, thank you. I tried to directly add the message instead of a pointer - should have checked the API more carefully ...